How to properly restore system state after shutdown in Java using Restore class?
Problem:
I am working on a Java project where I need to restore the system state after a shutdown caused by an event (such as a PowerOut or WindowMalfunction). When the system is restored, it should only resume the events that occur after the shutdown, not replay all events from the start.
However, the current implementation outputs all events from the beginning, even the ones that happened before the shutdown. I want it to only resume from the point after the shutdown event. I'm using serialization to save and restore the system state, and I’ve implemented a Fixable interface to handle issues during recovery.
Expected Behavior:
When running the command java GreenhouseControls -d dump.out, it should restore the system and only output the events after the event that caused the shutdown.
For example:
System restored from dump.out
Restored system state:
Power On: false
Resuming system...
Bing!
Terminate

Actual Behavior:
Instead of resuming from after the shutdown, it outputs all the events from the beginning:
Restored system state:
Power On: false
Resuming system...
Restarting system
Thermostat on night setting
Light is on
Light is off
...
(Outputs everything from the start)

Code:
Here is the relevant part of the code that shows how I’m trying to restore the system state.
// Minimal example: GreenhouseControls.java
import java.io.*;

public class GreenhouseControls implements Serializable {
    protected boolean light = false;
    protected boolean water = false;
    protected String thermostat = "Day";
    protected boolean fans = false;
    protected boolean windowok = true;
    protected boolean poweron = true;
    private int errorcode;

    public interface Fixable {
        void fix();
        void log();
    }

    public class PowerOn implements Fixable {
        @Override
        public void fix() {
            poweron = true;
            errorcode = 0;
        }
        @Override
        public void log() {
            System.out.println("Power restored");
        }
    }

    public int getError() {
        return errorcode;
    }

    public Fixable getFixable(int errorcode) {
        if (errorcode == 2) return new PowerOn();
        return null;
    }

    public void shutdown(int errorcode, String errorMessage) {
        this.errorcode = errorcode;
        try (ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("dump.out"))) {
            out.writeObject(this);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.exit(0);
    }
}


// Minimal example: Restore.java
import java.io.*;

public class Restore {
    private GreenhouseControls gc;

    public Restore(String filename) {
        try (ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(filename))) {
            gc = (GreenhouseControls) in.readObject();
            System.out.println("System restored from " + filename);
        } catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("Error during system restore: " + e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void fixAndResume() {
        if (gc != null) {
            System.out.println("Restored system state:");
            System.out.println("Power On: " + gc.poweron);
            if (gc.getError() != 0) {
                GreenhouseControls.Fixable fixable = gc.getFixable(gc.getError());
                fixable.fix();
                fixable.log();
            }
            System.out.println("Resuming system...");
            // Instead of resuming all events, it should only resume from after the shutdown
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Restore restore = new Restore("dump.out");
        restore.fixAndResume();
    }
}

What I’ve Tried:

I’ve implemented the Restore class, which deserializes the GreenhouseControls object saved during shutdown.

The system state is restored correctly, and the issue that caused the shutdown is fixed using the Fixable interface. However, the program outputs all events from the beginning instead of resuming only from the point after the event that caused the shutdown.


Question:
How can I modify my Restore class or system logic so that when I run java GreenhouseControls -d dump.out, it only resumes the events after the shutdown, rather than repeating all events from the beginning?

it is not clear what meaning you put in "resumes the events ...". Your system saves state and restores state.

You say the line "Restarting system" is being logged - but where does that happen in the code? I don't see that string anywhere.

There is no way for others to help if you've omitted chunks of code relating to your issue. Add a [mre] which shows the messages you haven't included. You should be able to easily verify whether the state before and after serialisation is correct.
